# Pulse audio is lagging and stuttering

Tags: audio, pulseaudio

I am using pulse audio to stream to my Ices2 Client.

During the start of a song and sometimes all the way through if I am mixing audio together, pulse audio begins to really lag...

As in it is stuttering most of the way through and sounds slightly slow motion.

And then it catches up and starts playing normally.

Any ideas on what I can do to fix this?

EDIT: It also happens (badly) when I change volume of an application.

Answer (score 1):

Check out the [PulseAudio Troubleshooting](https://wiki.archlinux.org/title/PulseAudio/Troubleshooting) page in Arch Wiki.

What helped me was switching to interrupt-based scheduling, by editing the following line in `/etc/pulse/default.pa`:

```
load-module module-udev-detect
```

I added `tsched=0` to it:

```
load-module module-udev-detect tsched=0
```

Interrupt-based scheduler can be further tweaked by editing `/etc/pulse/daemon.conf`. Crackling, stuttering and lagging are all affected by the following two parameters - higher values mean more lag but less skips:

```
default-fragments = 3
default-fragment-size-msec = 5
```